# Parameters are not getting passed in URL Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

Please find below code for Javascript

```
function viewGraph(){
    var countries=document.getElementsByName("exceptionRecord");
    var size=document.getElementById("size").value;
    var checkedElements="";
    var count=0;
    for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(countries[i].checked){
            checkedElements=checkedElements+"&country"+count+"="+document.getElementsByName("exceptionRecord")[i].value;
            count++;
        }
    }
    checkedElements=checkedElements+"&size="+count;
    checkedElements=checkedElements+"&region="+document.getElementsByName("region")[0].value;
    checkedElements=checkedElements+"&measure="+document.getElementsByName("measure")[0].value;
    alert(checkedElements);
    document.trendReport.action="Trending.jsp?method1=viewGraph&action=generateReport"+checkedElements;
    document.trendReport.submit();
}
```

Also Please find my JSP code

```
<form name="trendReport" method="post" onsubmit="viewGraph()">
<input type="submit" value="View Graph" >
</form>
```

If I'm trying to submit this form its not passing the parameters which i have given in action its only redirecting to Trending.jsp

Can any one please help
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @AmitJoki He is about the code he is provided.

Comment: What did you get in `alert(checkedElements);` ?

Comment: I did not give my complete JSP code here but checkedElements is working fine

Comment: Do you have an element with ID `size` in your `HTML`?

Comment: I've checked your code and the problem was that there wasn't an element with ID `size`, an element with NAME `region` and an element with NAME `measure`. Everything else works fine.

Comment: no no in my actual jsp code i have those elements i don't have an issue there as my issue is only to do with passing parameters in the URL i did not give my complete jsp code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add method attribute to your form

```
<form name="trendReport" action="" method="get" onsubmit="viewGraph()">
    <input type="submit" value="View Graph" >
</form>
```

Note: you don't need to submit form by javascript as it is already in submit event.